# Can Windivert injects packets larger than MTU?

Tags: sockets, tcp, winpcap, mtu, lso

I used winpcap and I got errors on "pcap_sendpacket", I fragmented the packet in little IP packets with the size of the MTU and did not work even wireshark didnt show errors in the packets which I fragmented.

Now I have this question, Can windivert inject packets larger than MTU? I need to know that before try to disable the "large send offload", if I disable that will me be able to send packet with winpcap larger than MTU, and with windivert? Is the only way to solve this?.

Sometimes in my program I have to fordward packet which I receive in winpcap with a size of 2300 bytes and my MTU has 1500 and It fails. If i receive the packet with windivert and send it with windivert will I have errors? Is a solution to disable the LSO?.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I have this question, Can windivert inject packets larger than MTU?

Yes you should be able to "inject" it.  However, the packet may be dropped (IPv6) or fragmented (IPv4) by the network en route to the destination.